# How to Deserialize JSON object[][] to a List<SomeObject>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using the Newtonsoft JSON.NET package.

The JSON I am working with has a nested property that by default deserializes to an object[][]. So for example you have something like this:

```
[
    ["George", "Washington", "555-555-1234", 47],
    ["Ronald", "Mcdonald", "555-222-3333", 50],
    ["Sterling", "Archer", "234-567-8901", 30]
]
```

And say I have created a Person class

```
public class Person{

    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
    public string Phone{ get; set;}
    public int Age{ get; set;}
}
```

How do I deserialize that object[][] to a nice, easy to use List of Person objects?

Comment: How does your JSON looks like ??

Comment: There is no easy way, but one possible way is to deserialize to a `List<string>` then iterate through it assigning values based on index (assuming the format is fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you will be able to get out of the box deserialization without some tinkering due to it being just plain arrays of `string` and not a nicely formatted JSON key/pair. This is what I would do:

```
public class Data 
{
    public List<List<string>> UserInfo {get;set;}
    public List<Person> ToPersonList()
    {
        return UserInfo.Select(info=> new Person 
        {
            FirstName = info[0],
            LastName = info[1],
            Phone = info[2],
            Age = Convert.ToInt32(info[3])
        });
    }
}
```

Then have Newtonsoft Deserialize to `Data` and then call `Data.ToPersonList()` to get your list of `Person`

Comment: How do you deserialize above data with Newtonsoft?

Comment: Newtonsoft JSON.NET - As mentioned by op in the first sentence

Answer (score 0):

Based off this answer: [Deserialization of Json without name fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13691550/6741868):

You could deserialize the JSON into a List, then a mapper function like this can help:

```
public Person PersonMapper(string[] input)
{
    return new Person {
        FirstName = input[0],
        LastName = input[1],
        Phone = input[2],
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(input[3])
    };
}
```

Of course this function assumes the order of indexes and fields is always 0, 1, 2, 3 and doesn't check for error cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var array = new object[3][];
        array[0] = new object[4] { "George", "Washington", "555-555-1234", 47 };
        array[1] = new object[4] { "Ronald", "Mcdonald", "555-222-3333", 50 };
        array[2] = new object[4] { "Sterling", "Archer", "234-567-8901", 30 };

        var list = new List<Person>();
        foreach (var r in array)
            list.Add(new Person() { FirstName = (string)r[0], LastName = (string)r[1], Phone = (string)r[2], Age = int.Parse((string)r[3]) });
```